# How to delete spaces in an "oracle home location"

Tags: oracle, oracle21c

Just downloaded oracle 21c, and am setting it up on my desktop. When I select the "option create and configure a single instance database" it gives me the error;

**"[INS-32922] The detected Oracle home location C:\Users\asutt\Downloads\WINDOWS.X64_213000_db_home (1) is invalid since it contains spaces."**

What are spaces in this context and how do I remove them?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
C:\Users\asutt\Downloads\WINDOWS.X64_213000_db_home (1)
                                                   -
                                                   ^
                                              this is a space
```

What to do? It looks as if you downloaded the same file twice; one of them had the original name, while another - so that it wouldn't overwrite previous version - has  `(1)` in its name.

I suggest you delete both and start over, possibly in a new location.

Or, you could rename it and add underline (e.g. `home_(1)` but I hate to see parenthesis when working with Oracle. Personally, I install my Oracle software into `C:\Oracle`.